# Consider the binomial distribution with n trials and probability p of success. For what value of k is P(X = k) maximized?

Tags: probability, distributions, binomial-distribution

I am struggling with the problem in the title. Intuitively, I know what value k should be; if n is an even number, then k = n/2; if n is odd, then k is the "central" trial, the number in the middle.

I know this because, IIRC, the binomial coefficient nCk increases, then reaches its maximum at the central number, and then decreases in a symmetrical manner.

I apologize if I'm not being clear; this is my first-ever mathematical stats course, and I might need some extra help before I'm fully comfortable with things.

Answer (score 6):

Comparing $P(X = k)$ with $P(X = k -1)$ we have that:

$$\frac{P(X = k)}{P(X = k-1)} = \frac{(n-k+1)p}{k(1 - p)}$$

Which means that for $P(X = k)\ge P(X = k-1)$ then $(n-k+1)p \ge k(1-p)$ which implies $k \le (n + 1)p$. Since $k$ must be an integer, the maximum is reached when $k = \lfloor(n+1)p\rfloor$.